# Can a War domain Cleric learn Fireball with Ritual Caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, cleric

I'm a Cleric and my Domain is War. I recently got to level 8 and decided to take the Ritual Caster Feat and choose Cleric. Certain Clerics can learn stuff like Fireball if they are in the Light Domain and stuff like that. Would I be able to learn that even though I am a War Cleric?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please check out our [help] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score 14):

No, you can't learn domain spells that aren't normally Cleric spells (except War spells). The Ritual Caster feat says:

> Choose one of the following classes: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard. You must choose your spells from that class’s spell list, and the spells you choose must have the ritual tag.

So if you choose Cleric, you can only learn ritual spells from the Cleric's spell list. Note that this means you couldn't learn *fireball* even if it was a Cleric spell, because it isn't a ritual spell.

Domain spells from outside the Cleric spell list have this special rule (emphasis mine):

> If you have a domain spell that doesn’t appear on the
>   cleric spell list, the spell is nonetheless a cleric spell **for you**.

So the domain spells aren't on the Cleric's spell list unless you are a Cleric with that domain.

This does mean that you should be able to use the spells from the War domain with Ritual Caster, but there's obviously no point to doing that. Those spells are always prepared for you, so you can cast them as a ritual at any time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

The Cleric's Domain Spells are very specific on which spells you gain access to as an expanded spell list. For War Clerics, they can gain:

> Cleric Level 1st - Divine Favor, Shield of Faith
>   3rd - Magic Weapon, Spiritual Weapon
>   5th - Crusader's Matle, Spirit Guardian
>   7th - Freedom of Movement, Stoneskin
>   9th - Flame Strike, Hold Monster

So, unless you multiclass into another caster with Fireball as a spell, no, you can't learn Fireball.

The Ritual Caster Feat only grants you spells with the Ritual Tag, the Second paragraph under *Ritual Caster* page 158:

> Choose one of the following classes: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer,
>   warlock, or wizard. You must choose your spells from that class’s spell list, **and the spells you choose must have the ritual tag**.

In conclusion:

1. Since Fireball isn't a Ritual, you can't cast it with that Feat; only Rituals can be learnt from this Feat.
2. Even if Fireball *were* a Ritual, it's not on the *Cleric's* spell list, it's only in the Light Cleric's *expanded* spell list (i.e. Domain Spells), so you still can't cast Fireball unless you choose Wizard or any class that *can* cast Fireball (our weird homebrewed Ritual Fireball, not the plain old Fireball) as a Ritual.